# How to detect that the URLs navigate to the same webpage

Tags: c#, url, html

I'm working with `webbrowser` tool trying to build my own browser.
Something that i'm having trouble doing is the history part.

When the document completes navigating , I search in my database if its URL doesn't exist then I add it to the history, else I just increase the `"counter"` of this page in the database.

The problem is that when I enter some pages each time it gives me different URL but it's the same page ! such as `google.com` , when I navigate to it it gives me in the first time (for example) : `https://www.google.co.il/?gws_rd=cr&ei=eBP-UtPCOMi84ASukoCAAw`

the second time I navigate :

`https://www.google.co.il/?gws_rd=cr&ei=rhP-UpW6CYG54ATAqIHIDg`

Is there a way to identify that both these URLs lead to the same page ??

I'm trying to do this because when I load the history to my application , many URLs are loaded that are leading to the same page.

Any help is appreciated , thanx in advance

Comment: It depends on what you mean by *same* page? If you ignore the query string part of the URL then you have the entry point of the page BUT that doesn't necessarily mean that it's the same page. The query string might be integral to the data served.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Uri object and ask for the [AbsolutePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.uri.absolutepath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property

Comment: It doesn't work it is '/' for both URLs, I notices the Host property is www.google.com for both URLs...

Answer (score 0):

I personally would expect my browser to have the history by URL and not by content (that's what you actually try to do as far as I understand). But if you want to avoid these multiple entries, you might calculate a hash code for each *content* received by that page and increase your counter.

The problem is that you cannot know what the server will do with that URL. It might be the same today and different tomorrow. I also wouldn't just go for the URL without the parameters because on other pages the parameter might make a really important difference.

Another note: In case you hash the content, you might want to exclude things like 404 pages (which can occur with different URLs and shouldn't be grouped under the same hash.)

Comment: The hashing part wouldn't be reliable enough, think about a site like [BBC news](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/) - the content on the main page changes all the time but the URL is *always* the same.